# docker-flink not showing all log statements

Tags: docker, log4j, apache-flink

I am using 2 [docker flink](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/flink/) images with [AMIDST](https://github.com/amidst/toolbox) and the following sample code. AMIDST is a probabilistic graphical model framework which supports Flink.

One image is running as JobManager the other as TaskManager. JM is reachable via DNS and I provide my own log4j.properties based on the startup script in bin/flink-console.sh used by these images.

```
public class ParallelMLExample {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParallelMLExample.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutionEnvironment env;

    //Set-up Flink session
    env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().disableSysoutLogging();

    //generate a random dataset
    DataFlink<DataInstance> dataFlink = new DataSetGenerator().generate(env, 1234, 1000, 5, 0);

    //Creates a DAG with the NaiveBayes structure for the random dataset
    DAG dag = DAGGenerator.getNaiveBayesStructure(dataFlink.getAttributes(), "DiscreteVar4");
    LOG.info(dag.toString());

    //Create the Learner object
    ParameterLearningAlgorithm learningAlgorithmFlink = new ParallelMaximumLikelihood();

    //Learning parameters
    learningAlgorithmFlink.setBatchSize(10);
    learningAlgorithmFlink.setDAG(dag);

    //Initialize the learning process
    learningAlgorithmFlink.initLearning();

    //Learn from the flink data
    LOG.info("########## BEFORE UPDATEMODEL ##########");
    learningAlgorithmFlink.updateModel(dataFlink);
    LOG.info("########## AFTER UPDATEMODEL ##########");

    //Print the learnt Bayes Net
    BayesianNetwork bn = learningAlgorithmFlink.getLearntBayesianNetwork();
    LOG.info(bn.toString());
}
}
```

The problem is that I only see LOG.info() entries up until the updateModel call. After that silence. If I comment out this call, I can see the other entries. I am silencing Flink entries on purpose here.

```
Creating flink_jobmanager_1  ... done
Creating flink_jobmanager_1  ...
Creating flink_taskmanager_1 ... done
Attaching to flink_jobmanager_1, flink_taskmanager_1
jobmanager_1   | Starting Job Manager
jobmanager_1   | config file:
taskmanager_1  | Starting Task Manager
jobmanager_1   | jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
taskmanager_1  | config file:
jobmanager_1   | jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager_1   | jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager_1  | jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
jobmanager_1   | taskmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager_1  | jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager_1   | taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
taskmanager_1  | jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024
jobmanager_1   | taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
taskmanager_1  | taskmanager.heap.mb: 1024
jobmanager_1   | parallelism.default: 1
taskmanager_1  | taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
jobmanager_1   | web.port: 8081
taskmanager_1  | taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
jobmanager_1   | blob.server.port: 6124
taskmanager_1  | parallelism.default: 1
jobmanager_1   | query.server.port: 6125
taskmanager_1  | web.port: 8081
jobmanager_1   | Starting jobmanager as a console application on host c16d9156ff68.
taskmanager_1  | blob.server.port: 6124
taskmanager_1  | query.server.port: 6125
taskmanager_1  | Starting taskmanager as a console application on host 76c78378d35c.
jobmanager_1   | 2018-02-18 15:31:42,809 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
taskmanager_1  | 2018-02-18 15:31:43,897 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
jobmanager_1   | 2018-02-18 15:32:18,667 INFO  com.ness.ParallelMLExample                                    - DAG
jobmanager_1   | DiscreteVar0 has 1 parent(s): {DiscreteVar4}
jobmanager_1   | DiscreteVar1 has 1 parent(s): {DiscreteVar4}
jobmanager_1   | DiscreteVar2 has 1 parent(s): {DiscreteVar4}
jobmanager_1   | DiscreteVar3 has 1 parent(s): {DiscreteVar4}
jobmanager_1   | DiscreteVar4 has 0 parent(s): {}
jobmanager_1   |
jobmanager_1   | 2018-02-18 15:32:18,679 INFO  com.ness.ParallelMLExample                                    - ########## BEFORE UPDATEMODEL ##########
```

The updateModel method starts with a new Configuration() then retrieves the data set. It then runs a map, reduce and collect against the supplied data set but does not seem to be messing with root loggers...

What am I missing?

Comment: Just adding that this lack of logging occurs when I simplify the task and remove dependencies to AMIDST. I commented out those calls and Added a straight filter, reduce and collect on DataSet created by hand.

Comment: So deloying WordCount on the jobmanager/taskmanager setup above shows the following entry `taskmanager_1  | The operator name DataSource (at getDefaultTextLineDataSet(WordCountData.java:70) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CollectionInputFormat)) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.` for any System.out.println()

Comment: launching flink with start-cluster.sh works well. Official docker image launched using docker-compose is not working for me.